# Summing BigInteger Digits

Tags: java, sum, biginteger, digits

I am trying to find the sum of the digits of the number 2^1000 and I am using Java BigInteger class for this. However, I could not make it real. Eventually, I get a 0 (zero) with the following code. What might be the problem?

Thanks...

---

After Kon's help I fixed the problem, but this time I get a wrong result. Can anyone see the problem with the algorithm?

```
public static void main(String []args) throws Exception
{
    BigInteger big = BigInteger.valueOf(2).pow(1000);
    BigInteger big2 = BigInteger.valueOf(0);


    //System.out.println(big);

    for(long i = 1; i<283; i++)
    {
         big2 = big2.add(big.mod(BigInteger.valueOf((long) Math.pow(10,i))).divide(BigInteger.valueOf((long)Math.pow(10,i-1))));
    }

    System.out.println(big2);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Trying to calculate each digit of `BigInteger` using *mod* is not very efficient, because of many method calls you are doing in the process. Instead you can simplify by doing the conversion to `String` and getting each digit straight away.

```
BigInteger big = BigInteger.valueOf(2).pow(1000);
String digits = big.toString();
int sum = 0;

for(int i = 0; i < digits.length(); i++) {
    int digit = (int) (digits.charAt(i) - '0');
    sum = sum + digit;
}

System.out.println(sum);
```

Comment: Thanks, I did not know that we can convert BigInteger to String that easy. Yours the best way I think. But I still wonder the problem with operations with BigInteger. Because when I check for 2^10 and 2^15, my code gives the correct result. If you have time and have a look and share your comment with me I would be pleased.

Comment: It seems you are hitting the limit of `long`, that you are using in the intermediate steps of the calculation. After 20-th digit, the `a` and `b` operands in `a.divide(b)` part of your calculation stop changing. Try doing a debug, or print out the individual results and you'll see what I mean.

Comment: I definetely got what you mean. I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1):

The [BigInteger](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html) class is immutable, therefore you have to assign the result of the operation to the variable itself.

```
big2.add(big.mod(BigInteger.valueOf((long) Math.pow(10,i))).divide(BigInteger.valueOf((long)Math.pow(10,i-1))));
```

should become

```
big2 = big2.add(big.mod(BigInteger.valueOf((long) Math.pow(10,i))).divide(BigInteger.valueOf((long)Math.pow(10,i-1))));
```

For more on immutable objects in Java, please take a look at [this documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/immutable.html).

Also, although your question is not specifically about this, using hard coded literal values in your loops is very bad practice. You want to loop over each digit in the BigInteger 2^1000. Well, you could get the number of digits using something like `big.toString().length()`.

Comment: Thanks a lot! It fixed the problem. But this time, it seems like that my algorithm was not correct because I get the wrong answer.

Comment: @ÖzgürDevrimArikan I would start by creating some sample program and creating some explicit BigInteger with value like "1234". Then try to loop over these digits and see what's happening. Keep in mind that once you have the BigInteger value of 2^1000, you can get this as a String (see my answer), then looping over the digits of a string is VERY easy and there are dozens of SO answers on how to do this.